# How to copy values from one column to another

Tags: sharepoint-designer, copy-and-paste

how can i copy values from one column to another? I'm using a workflow but i cant see the option "Copy List Item"

ps: I'm using Sharepoin On-line

Comment: For example you have 2 columns `place` and `address`. Once you create an item with value only in `address`. You would want to run a workflow and set value into `place`. Is that what you are looking for? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Are you on SharePoint 2010 platform of workflow?

Comment: No, I'm using 2013

Comment: You haven't marked any Answer as answer.. could it be you mean you want to copy a Column from Item A to another Column in Item B ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For another Column in the same List (or another List on the same Site) you have to use **Update Item action**

[image]

Comment: From a column on a same list

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 site. And creating a workflow using `SharePoint Designer 2013` you will be prompted to select the platform type either 2010 or 2013. You can choose as per your requirement as Action which we need `Set Field in Current Item` is available in both the platforms.

So here is step.

1. Create a workflow for Item Creating
2. Add an action from the ribbon control `Set Field in Current Item`. Refer below screen shot.

[image]

As shown in image, click on field link, you will get a drop area from where you can select in which field you want the value to be stored. i.e. 'Place'

Next click on value link, you will be see a dialogue box , from `Field from source` drop down select your column name from which value will fetched and stored.