# Sharepoint 2013 - copy list value from one list to another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, copy-content

I have some list values (which are currently calculated values) in List A. I would like to transfer some of these values to list B. The values are currency - it is sort of a costing sheet.
I am hoping a workflow will be the solution. I have found solutions from for within the current list but not transferring from one list to another.

Example below:

LIST A
Total Accommodation - calculated currency field
Total Transport - calculated currency field
Total Backfill - calculated currency field
Total Incidentals - calculated currency field
Total Resources - calculated currency field

LIST B
Total Accommodation - currency field
Total Transport - currency field
Total Backfill - currency field
Total Incidentals - currency field
Total Resources - currency field

Here is a cut down of what I have done and is working - I found that Create List item worked where Update list did not (for my example I have left off Total Backfill, Total Incidentals and Total Resources - just to simplify).

So I created the new list - I then had to add in the other fields I was collecting data from...the process looks like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have found this post item - my workflow show it is without error and then it fails. 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152801/how-to-copy-values-from-one-column-to-another

Comment: Where you have attached your workflow on item creating or updating?and both the lists are on same site or they are in cross site collection?

Comment: Have a look at this if you can use Flow http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/04/29/auto-move-sharepoint-list-items-using-flow/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If your list is in the same site collection, You can do a workflow like this 

Create item in Test list A
```

Comment: My list is in the same site collection
If I create an item in Test list A - I cant see how this is going to transfer to list B

Comment: Thanks heaps - I've just got it to work. I had previously tried Update item which failed with errors. Its working great.

Comment: I do now have a further problem.
I can get the value - but I need to marry it up with a specific item ID. I will include more detail above in my original question.

Comment: Never mind - I needed to include some more fields to copy in my original. Thanks again.